# Is Stochastic gradient descent a classifier or an optimizer?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, gradient-descent

I am new to Machine Learning and I am trying analyze the classification algorithm for a project of mine. I came across `SGDClassifier` in `sklearn` library. But a lot of papers have referred to SGD as an optimization technique. Can someone please explain how is `SGDClassifier` implemented?

Comment: Stochastic gradient descent is a stochastic approximation of the gradient descent optimization method for minimizing an objective function that is written as a sum of differentiable functions. In other words, SGD tries to find minima or maxima by iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from SGD sikit-learn documentation

`loss="hinge"`: (soft-margin) linear Support Vector Machine,
`loss="modified_huber"`: smoothed hinge loss,
`loss="log"`: logistic regression

Answer (score 3):

[SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) is indeed a technique that is used to find the minima of a function. 
`SGDClassifier` is a linear classifier (by default in `sklearn` it is a linear SVM) that uses SGD for training (that is, looking for the minima of the loss using SGD). According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html):

> SGDClassifier is a Linear classifiers (SVM, logistic regression, a.o.)
>   with SGD training.
>
> This estimator implements regularized linear models with stochastic
>   gradient descent (SGD) learning: the gradient of the loss is estimated
>   each sample at a time and the model is updated along the way with a
>   decreasing strength schedule (aka learning rate). SGD allows minibatch
>   (online/out-of-core) learning, see the partial_fit method. For best
>   results using the default learning rate schedule, the data should have
>   zero mean and unit variance.
>
> This implementation works with data represented as dense or sparse
>   arrays of floating point values for the features. The model it fits
>   can be controlled with the loss parameter; by default, it fits a
>   linear support vector machine (SVM).

Answer (score 0):

Lets seggregate each word in simple english meaning

Stochastic - Random,
Gradient - slope,
Descent - downwards

Basically, this technique is used as an "optimizing algorithm" for finding the parameters with minimal convex loss/cost function.

By which we can find out the slope of the line which has minimal loss for linear classifiers i.e. (SVM & Logistic Regression)

Some of the other ways in which it is performed:

1. Batch Gradient Descent
2. Stochastic Gradient Descent
3. Mini-batch

For more details, on the above please go through the referred link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-stochastic-gradient-descent-sgd/